# What does "Christnique" mean in "1985" by Anthony Burgess?

Tags: meaning, anthony-burgess, nineteen-eighty-five

This word appears twice in *1985* by Anthony Burgess:

> ‘That’s it. Without us how would the **Christniques** get on?’

> They go out wanting to be cracked. Then they practise the **Christnique** of loving your enemies.

According to Wiktionary, "nique" means "A small thing" in French. I know that sometimes the word "nique" is used as a vulgar word.

Answer (score 4):

From the context, I believe that Burgess is using "Christnique" in two different ways.

In the first phrase:

> Without us how would the Christniques get on?

"-nique" seems to be used as a Latinised form of the common suffix "-nik", which the [dictionary tells us](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-nik) is:

> a suffix of nouns that refer, usually derogatorily, to persons who
> support or are concerned or associated with a particular political
> cause or group, cultural attitude, or the like

which is used to form words such as beatnik and peacenik. So Burgess is coining the term "Christnik" as a slightly derogatory term for Christians.

In the second use, however:

> Then they practise the Christnique of loving your enemies.

"Christnique" seems to be used here as a portmanteau between "Christian" and "technique", to refer to the Christian doctrine of loving your enemies, as a tool to convert non-Christians by good example.

Comment: I haven't read 1985, but knowing a bit about Burgess and A Clockwork Orange, it might be a bit more neutral. He likes to coin new words mixing English and Russian, and the Russian -nik is an agentive suffix without the same shade of meaning it gets in English.

Answer (score 2):

It is a while since I read Burgess' book; it may be a spelling variant of the suffix [-nik](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-nik#English), used by Burgess' characters in the novel to refer to those who profess Christianity as their religion or practise it.